# Manipulate an image before saving or after to the media libary

Tags: media-library

I want to add a colour effect and pixelate etc to my images. So the best way I think of is to do the manipulation of all images prior to saving.

I have the created the class to call and manipulate the image.

Which is the best hook / filter I could use to perform such a task, to run my code before the image is saved. Or if there is a way to get it done after the image(s) have been saved?

Comment: Keep in mind that the actual modification of the file is a generic PHP question

Comment: I have created the class  to do the manipulation I just need a way to get the image added to Wordpress to go through this class before or after its been created.